# How i can generate a DES3 key coded in base64 in openssl

Tags: openssl, key

How can I generate a **DES3** key encoded in **base64** using **openssl** tool?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question is a bit terse: did you already try something yourself? Where exactly do you get stuck?

Answer (score 4):

For a DES3 key, you need 192 random bits (i.e. 24 bytes).  The following `openssl` command will produce 24 random bytes, encoded using base64 encoding:

```
openssl rand -base64 24
```

Comment: Technically the low bit of each byte of a TDEA/triple-DES/3DES key, like a classic/single-DES key/DEA, should be set for **odd byte parity**. OpenSSL API can do that, but not commandline. However, most modern implementations ignore these bits, which are no longer needed.